# Need to converge two matrix value together in form of tuple

Tags: python

Need to converge two matrix value together in form of tuple .

1. Matrix

0 1 2 3

1 1 1 1

2 2 1 3

3 2 3 1

2. Matrix

0 1 2 3

1 4 6 7

2 3 5 6

3 1 3 5

Output required is

0    1        2       3

1  (1,4)   (1,6)   (1,7)

2  (2,3)   (1,5)   (3,6)

3  (2.1)   (3,3)   (1,5)

where first row and column is index of the matrix.

Comment: How are your matrices stored?  As list or lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrix is list of lists, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) -

```
from random import randint
a = [[randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
b = [[randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
c = [list(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

```
>>> a
[[8, 4, 1], [4, 3, 4], [2, 5, 5]]
>>> b
[[2, 2, 1], [6, 1, 7], [10, 3, 5]]
>>> c
[[(8, 2), (4, 2), (1, 1)], [(4, 6), (3, 1), (4, 7)], [(2, 10), (5, 3), (5, 5)]]
```

If you don't want to use `zip`, using list comprehension -

```
c = [list((a[i][j], b[i][j]) for j in range(len(a[0]))) for i in range(len(a))]
```

Both ways work even when `a` and `b` is not square matrix as long as the dimensions of both matrices are identical.